# Как сохранить изменения в OllyDbg v2?

Tags: отладка

Изменил нужные мне байты в отладчике. Через отладчик программа работает. Как сохранить этот измененный файл?
Точнее дописал пару инструкций в блоке выравнивания. Надо сохранить программу и изменить точку входа. Как сохранить программу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Правой кнопкой мыши по коду
2. copy to executable
3. all modifications
4. вылезет окошко в котором нужно нажать правую кнопку мыши
5. save to file
6. имя файла
7. ок

Answer (score -1):

1. Edit
2. Copy all modifications to executable
3. save file (yes)
4. Name.exe